# How can I save some `json` data(array) on `button` click, as `someName.json` file on my local drive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of objects that I would like to save as `.json` file on my local drive, how can I achieve that.

I know that I can copied to clipboard and paste. but I am looking for solution that save that array as `.json`

`const arrayToCopy = ['somevalue', 3, 'anotherValue'];`

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
   this.exportAsJson();
  }}
>
 Export
</Button>
```

saving as `json` function

```
exportAsJson = () => {

}
```

Comment: data is coming from server

Comment: @Estradiaz do you some code examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here try like this

```
exportAsJson = () => {
  const str = JSON.stringify(arrayToCopy);
  const data = this.encode( str ); 
  const blob = new Blob( [ data ], {
    type: 'application/json'
  });

  const element = document.createElement("a");
  element.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  element.download = "myFile.json";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
}
```